# Going against, yet with respect to, the cross?

Tags: mathematics, wordplay, steganography

> What number do you get deriving with going against the cross, yet with respect to the cross,
>   Then removing the with and using some imagination with the product?

Hint 1:

> In this puzzle the crosses aren't the same.

Hint 2:

> Prefixes are nice. You'll have to use them twice, at least thrice.

Hint 3:

> When you cross the cross, be sure to beg mercy for it.

Final Hint:

> The answer takes only one finger.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! If you take a tour here you can get a badge https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> 6

Reasoning:

> Going against the cross refers to sin, and with deriving with respect to the cross (x) gives us the derivative of sin(x) as cos(x).
>  Now, removing the with, as one of the prefixes meaning "with" is "co", we get s(x).
>  This is in the form of the product sx, but taking the product with some *imagination* (a.k.a. *i*, or the square root of -1) gives us six or 6.

Hint 1:

> We obviously used cross in the religious sense and cross in the symbol sense.

Hint 2:

> We used the prefix in sin(x) or sin, and cos(x) or co-. (I'm a little skeptical about the first one)

Hint 3:

> I found this site: http://www.namboothiri.com/articles/counting.htm, but this is the hint that makes me most doubt my answer.

Comment: Good job! there are some minor errors in how you interpreted the hints but the overall reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the answer is:

> C

Because deriving an integration you lose the "cross", and when integrating you gain a "cross" with some imaginary constant.

Comment: not quite what I was thinking of, but it's a good answer given the available information, I'll add a hint.

Answer (score 3):

It’s:

> either sin(x) or -sin(x), I can’t tell whether the negative is inside or outside the parentheses (assuming I interpreted that right, which I probably didn’t).

I looked up

> “with” prefixes and figured cos was close enough to com- or col-. And once you derive that, “sin” obviously fits the wordplay, so it’s something with that.

Comment: So close, you've almost got it. You've got a couple things wrong but by far you're the closest yet.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> $i = \sqrt{-1} $

I think it has to do with...

> The derivative of $$ (i * x) \frac{d}{dx}$$

By against the cross, it means

> deriving across the multiplication(the cross being $*$)

By with the cross, it means

> deriving in terms of $x$ ($x$ is the cross here)

Comment: again, not quite, you've got one cross right though!

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> A determinant?

Two possible interpretations:

> The "pitchfork" method of evaluating a 2 by 2 or 3 by 3 determinant, via products of elements in "wrapped diagonals", then you subtract the sum for one direction minus the sum for the other direction.

Or:

> The determinant can be interpreted in terms of an exterior product, which is a universal "antisymmetric" product - maybe "antisymmetric" is what is meant by "against the cross"?

Comment: Hmmm, the cross really seems to be throwing people off. But your answer is probably the 2nd closest thus far. But I enjoy the interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> 1

Steps which I took to get the answer.

>   "
>   *deriving with going against the cross, yet with respect to the cross*
>   " would mean derivative(cos(x)) / derivative(x) , which would give
>   **-sin(x)**
>   . I got cos(x) by adding prefix ‘co-‘ to sin(x) because of the ‘with’.
>
>   "
>   *removing the with*
>   " would give me "
>   *deriving going against the cross, yet with respect to the cross*
>   " , now change the meaning of cross , so it might mean negative(derivative(x)) / derivative(cos(x)), which would give
>   **-1/sin(x)**
>   .
>
>   Product of result 1 and 2 would give me
>   **1**
>   as the answer.

Comment: I have changed the steps on how i got the answer.